# How to get the type of a Tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm looking for something similar to the effects of:

```
x.get_shape()
```

that will give the type of `x`. Is there is any function for this?

Comment: where did you see that `x.get_shape()` returns the type of `x`? do you want to know the shape of a tensor? `x.get_shape()` returns the TensorShape of the x variable, then what do you want?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use [get_shape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/faq#tensor_shapes) to get the shape of a tensorflow variable.

```
>>> x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 100]))
>>> x.get_shape()
(256, 100)
```

You can use [dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType) property to get the type of a tensorflow variable.

```
>>> x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 100]))
>>> x.dtype
<dtype: 'float32_ref'>
```

You can use [as_numpy_dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType) property of dtype to convert from [tf.dtype](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dtypes/DType) to [numpy dtype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html).

```
>>> x = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256, 100]))
>>> x.dtype.as_numpy_dtype
<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Comment: I get this error for:           tf.Print(self._batch_val.dtype, [self._batch_val.dtype], "dtype of batch_val: ")
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.dtypes.DType'> to Tensor. Contents: <dtype: 'float32'>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Shibani you don't need to use `tf.Print()` for printing the type of a Tensor because the Tensor's type does not change during the session run. The Tensor type is determined when you build the graph, so just use `print(x.dtype)`.

Answer (score 16):

To get the type you can do

```
x.dtype
```