# how to build and train a model on non-symbolic tensors ( I need to convert tensor to numpy in decoder function)

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensor, autoencoder

Basically, I am writing an autoencoder in which the decoder function has some extra steps and needs to convert tensors to numpy, apply some functions on the numpy array and finally convert the numpy array back the to tensor.

```py
latent_dim=256

def encoder(train):

    conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3),strides=2, activation='relu',  padding='same', name='myconv1')(train)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    x = Flatten()(conv2)
    latent = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_vector')(x)
    return latent

def decoder( latent): 
    x = Dense(256)(latent)
    latent = Reshape((16, 16, 1))(x)
    conv3 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3),strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(latent)
    decoded = Conv2DTranspose(32, (3, 3),strides=2, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(conv3)
    decoded = Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3), padding='same')(decoded)
    decoded = Activation('tanh', name='decoder_output')(decoded)

    final_output= extrafunction(decoded, myid, sn, header, sess)

   return final_output


def extrafunction( decoded, sess):

    with sess.as_default():
        sess.run(var)
        # convert to numpy
        decoded=decoded.eval()

    # In this section, I run some external function with the decoded variable as the input to that function

    outputs=externalfunction(decoded) # outputs is in numpy
    outputs= tf.convert_to_tensor(outputs, dtype=tf.float64)

    return outputs
```

since the external function needs to convert the tensor to numpy, using symbolic tensors to build the model as

```py
X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 64,64,1])
encoder_op = encoder(X)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)
```

will generate the error on

```py
decoded=decoded.eval()
 InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_2' with dtype float and shape [?,64,64,1]
```

On the other hand, if I use the real tensors (non-symbolic one), I got the following error on the first line of encoder function.

```
ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.
```

I need help to fix this issue. I do not know how to define my model, build and train it with this configuration. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: your `decoder` have a Dense layer first which need a 2D inputs and you are feeding a 4D input

Comment: Thats not true. the output of encoder function is in shape of (?, 256). 
my problem is on how build and train my model considering the numpy conversion in decoder and not about the structure of the network.

Comment: I haven't seen the edit you made, what is `decoded` doing here?

Comment: the `decoded` variable is the typical output of decoder function which has been converted to numpy.  some functions will apply on the numpy `decoded` in `externalfunction`

Comment: what is the tensor shape of `decoded` before feeding into `externalfunction` and `extrafunction`

Comment: the feeding shape to both is (?, 64, 64, 1)

Comment: @Samira what is the type of the decoded variable that you are passing to external function?

Comment: @Mina before calling the external function, the decoded variable has been converted to numpy array by ( decoded=decoded.eval() ) . And that's exactly where generates error.  By the time of defining the model, as it needs to be done by symbolic tensors in keras,  the eval() fails as it requires real tensors .

Comment: @Samira I understand where your error is raised. I would like to know what the "Type" of decoded is when you pass it here outputs=externalfunction(decoded) . Can you just print the "type" before passing it to the function?

Comment: @Mina It is <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'> with the size of (?, 64, 64, 1)

Comment: @Samira  based on the error on eval, it seems like the tensor should be of type float when you pass it, can you check the dtype of the tensor and confirm if it's actually float? here's how to get the dtype: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758315/how-to-get-the-type-of-a-tensor/42758444